# How do you extract sub strings from a string using regex?

Tags: regex, string, parsing

I have this string

Type: Book Year: 1991 Title: "This is book 1" ISBN: 1234567890 Pages: 500 Authors: "Smith, John";"Brown, Jack" MediaType: PaperBack

I wanted to extract the following sub-strings

```
Book
1991
"This is book 1"
1234567890
500
"Smith, John"
"Brown, Jack"
PaperBack
```

So far, I have extracted the first 2 strings using the following pattern

```
(\w+:)([\w\s]*\b)(\w+:)([\d\s]*\b)(\w+\b:)
```

I had many attempts to extract the string "This is book 1" but I can't seem to make out the next group pattern for this.  I tried this one `("[^"]*")` but it returns with no matches and I can't seem to get to the rest of the strings.

Your inputs are much appreciated.

Comment: which lang or tool are you running?

Comment: `("[^"]*")` should work. Did you take into account the space before the quotes? Like this - `(\s*"[^"]*")`

Comment: C# but I am trying it first in this website.. https://www.myregextester.com/index.php#sourcetab

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid now... I forgot about the space.  Thank you... I will move on until I get to another issue.

Comment: How do you deal with strings with one, or two, or three authors?  Is that possible to parse if there's variable number or authors?

Comment: @Nerf72 I know the solution you are looking for. please inform in which language you are working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex.

```
@"(?<=: ).*?(?=\s+(?:\w+:)|$)"
```

In c#, you may use

```
@"(?<=:\s+).*?(?=\s+(?:\w+:)|$)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bP7vZ8/1)

Comment: You need to print the matched group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will do the work you are seeking.

```
\w+:\s*(\w+|".+?(?="\s)")
```

And to learn how it is working or matching, check the below link. The Explanation box in the top right corner to learn about the regex. (if the boxes are empty please input the string and regex manually)

https://regex101.com/r/rW8eB9/1